# What is Ethereum's inflationary model going to be after switching to Casper?

Tags: casper, serenity, block-reward

Some time ago I read Vitalik Buterin's [blog post about possible attitude to inflation and transaction fees](https://blog.ethereum.org/2016/07/27/inflation-transaction-fees-cryptocurrency-monetary-policy/). From it it followed that nothing was decided yet and there are various possibilities. Has a decision been taken and will block reward and/or transaction fee mechanism change with Serenity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there isn't anything set in stone, as the development community is debating the issue. There are arguments for reducing the issuance rate of Ether even leading up to POS. See : https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/186 . But these are still at discussion stage and not concrete code.

Comment: Concise answer. Also, [this post](https://np.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/5izcf5/lets_talk_about_the_projected_coin_supply_over/dbc66rd) is relevant.